# Carga condicional

Tags: php, wordpress

hola buenas tengo este codigo para que no carge en todo el blog pero lo que necesito es  que no carge en sobre mi en la la portada del sitio y en contacto hay alguna manera de hacerlo??

`````
        if ( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_archive() ) {
           remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yasr_add_scripts');
        }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_yasr_header', 1);````
`````

Comment: [La función `is_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) admite varios parámetros que sirven para identificar una página en específico, por ejemplo el ID. Puedes por tanto agregar algo como: `is_page(ELIDDELAPAGINA)`

Comment: Gracias perdona por mi ignorancia como podría modificar el código para meter el id en ese mismo código??

Comment: En Wordpress cada página y post tiene un ID numérico. Lo puedes obtener por ejemplo abriendo la página en modo edición, si revisas la URL en la barra del navegador, será el valor numérico que ves en esa URL. Con eso bastaría, dado que es un valor fijo, no necesitas obtenerlo de forma dinámica en este caso.